# Why is fputcsv producing duplicate columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, duplicates

I am adding a download button to a WordPress site that will query our database, and offer up the result as a CSV.

Everything works, **except the CSV produced has a duplicate column for each column it returns.**

We have checked the SQL query and it does not have duplicates.

Here's how we are generating the CSV:

```
$rows = //Call to SQL query function
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, array_keys($rows));

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

$filename = "EventResults.csv";
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

We turn the SQL return into a PHP array like this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
 $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->fetchAll();
```

The results look like this:

```
Lance,Lance,Armstrong,Armstrong,DEX,DEX,70,70,1,1,60,60,SEC,SEC,"10; 20; 30; 40","10; 20; 30; 40"
```

When they should look like this:

```
Lance,Armstrong,DEX,70,1,60,SEC,"10; 20; 30; 40"
```

What is causing the duplicates, and how can we get rid of them?

Comment: Maybe you're fetching the record with a function that returns them both with numeric keys and column names as keys?

Comment: Okay, after taking a close look at $row, it seems like you're correct. However, we don't know how to avoid this. Is there a way to ignore those values? Can we remove them? Prevent them from ever being put in the array? How would you handle this problem?

Comment: I agree with @Maerlyn, some functions/libraries that query databases in php can get the result set as both an associative and a numerical indexed array, which may be causing the issue. It would be useful to know how you're retrieving your resultset.

Comment: @CaptainStack I would approach it by looking at how I'm generating the resultset and fix it there, are you able to post that code?

Comment: @Alex.Ritna, The problem is definitely that it is key-indexed and numerically indexed. I posted how we turn the SQL into a PHP array. See anything? How would you fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PDO method `fetchAll()` has a parameter `fetch_style` which [as documented](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) will return an array with both numerical and named associative keys causing you to have duplicates when you iterate over the array.

You can set it using one of the PDO Fetch constants documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) - they all start with `PDO::FETCH_` and use that to get either an associative array (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`) or a numerical array (`PDO::FETCH_NUM`)

```
return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: In my case, I had to change from mysql_fetch_array() to mysql_fetch_assoc().

Answer (score 0):

This works in MSSQL to prevent duplicate columns:

```
while ( $row = mssql_fetch_array($results, MSSQL_ASSOC) ) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);     
}
```